# Does this matrix operation exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, hadamard-product

let $\mathbf{r}_p(u)=(1,u,u^2,\ldots,u^p)'\in\mathbb{R}^{1+p}$ and let
$$\mathbf{R}_p = [\mathbf{r}_p(x_1), \mathbf{r}_p(x_2), \cdots, \mathbf{r}_p(x_n)]'_{n\times(1+p)}.$$
Moreover, let $\mathbf{Z}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Is there any way to obtain the following matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}Z_1\mathbf{r}_p(x_1), Z_2\mathbf{r}_p(x_2), \cdots, Z_n\mathbf{r}_p(x_n)\end{bmatrix}'_{n\times(1+p)}$$
using matrix operations that involve $\mathbf{Z}$ and $\mathbf{R}_p$? The only one I've been able to obtain was
$$(\mathbf{Z}\boldsymbol{\iota}_{1+p}')\odot \mathbf{R}_p,$$
where $\boldsymbol{\iota}_k$ is a $k\times 1$ vector of ones and $\odot$ denotes the Hadamard product. I'd like not to use the Hadamard product though, but it seems to me the only way to go.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Turn the $z$ vector into a diagonal matrix, i.e. $\;{R_p\cdot\operatorname{Diag}(z)}\;$

Comment: @greg the multiplication you suggest involves non-conformable matrices. did you mean $\mathrm{Diag}(z)R_p$?

Comment: Your notation is confusing. You put a prime on the definitions of $r_p{\;\rm and\;}R_p\,$ which I **assume** denotes the transpose operation.  So $R_p$ is actually a $(p+1)\times n$ matrix, in which the multiplication should be done as in my original comment.

Comment: I don't think the notation is confusing as $r_p$ is defined clearly as a column vector in the first line. anyhow, thanks for helping.